# Wire desktop shows white screen

Tags: 22.04, white-screen

Since today my Wire desktop app only shows a white screen.
It starts with the usual loading screen and fetching messages but then shows a blank page only.
Messages get delivered - I get the respective notifications - so it is not an issue with the connection but with displaying.
Menu dropdowns appear but if I select e.g. `Preferences`, nothing shows up.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, the issue appears on both tested systems.
It also appears on both the snap-version and installation via deb-package.
I tried restarting, reinstalling, resizing the window and changing Ubuntu themes, with no effect.

Starting wire from the terminal shows an error and warnings:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: cannot find desktop file "/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/wire_Wire.desktop"

(wire-desktop:11969): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:24:37.624: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1413:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(wire-desktop:11969): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:24:37.627: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3286:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(wire-desktop:11969): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:24:37.628: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3748:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
```

The file in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` is named `wire_wire.desktop` (no capital 'w'). I don't know where the wrong name is stored but I renamed the file to `wire_Wire.desktop`, which solved the error but not the white screen.
Uninstalling `gtk_common_themes` resolved the warnings but the white screen still persists.

I'm happy for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now by installing via debian repository
[github.com/wireapp/wire-desktop/...](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-desktop/wiki/How-to-install-Wire-for-Desktop-on-Linux). Both the regular and internal (beta) version are working fine (although, of course, the message history is lost on every reinstallation).

I still do not know what caused the issue with the debian package and snap install, though.